# Add values ​from the table conditioned to a criterion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Add values ​​from the table with criteria.
Attached table example:
It would be equal to the sum of product values.

[Table values and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6VWY.png)

CONTROLLER

```
class comparativeController < ApplicationController 
  def index
    @cashflows= cashflow.total
  end 
end
```

MODEL

```
class dailycashflow < ApplicationRecord
  def self.total
    self.sum(:value)   
  end
end
```

VIEW

`<td><%= @dailycashflow%></td></tr>`

Comment: "Sum all values ​​from customers, separate suppliers" -> what are customers and suppliers in your application? What does 'separate' mean here?

Comment: A new table example:
It would be equal to the sum if of excel.

Product Value
A 2
A 4
B 6
C 5
D 1
E 3
A 2
D 1
E 4
-------------

RESULTS 
 
Product Value
A 8
B 6
C 5
D 2
E 7

Answer (score 0):

I have a example

```
 a =  [
       {:name=>"A", :value=>2}, 
       {:name=>"A", :value=>4}, 
       {:name=>"B", :value=>6}, 
       {:name=>"C", :value=>5}, 
       {:name=>"A", :value=>2}
   ]
 a.group_by {|item| item[:name]}.map do |_, colection|
   colection.reduce do |result, item|
     result[:value] += item[:value]
     result
   end
 end
------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: [
   {:name=>"A", :value=>8}, 
   {:name=>"B", :value=>6}, 
   {:name=>"C", :value=>5}
  ]
```

or

```
 a.reduce([]) do |result, item|
   result_i = result.find { |result_i| result_i[:name] == item[:name]}
   if result_i
     result_i[:value] += item[:value]
     result
   else
     result << item
   end
end
```

[image]